# FullCalendar Populate Events from Database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar, specifically the one that comes with SmartAdmin. I need to get the events from the database and display them on the calendar.

This is the sample code I need to change to Asp.Net C# server-side (Entity Framework with LINQ):

```
events: [
{
     title: 'Event Title',
     start: new Date(y, m, 10, 00, 30),
     description: 'Long Description',
     className: ["event", "bg-color-red"],
     icon: 'fa-clock-o'
}
```

Update: Latest efforts include using JSON, trying to make the FullCalendar to read it and display it.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private string LoadEventLog()
    {
        using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
        {
            var query = (from el in context.EventLog
                         join et in context.EventTypes on el.eventType_FK equals et.id
                         join usr in context.Users on el.users_FK equals usr.id
                         orderby el.rowCreatedDT descending

                         select new EventLogInfo2()
                         {
                             id = el.id,
                             eventType_FK = el.eventType_FK,
                             eventType = et.eventType,
                             rowCreatedDT = el.rowCreatedDT,
                             message = el.message,
                             userFullName = usr.name + " " + usr.lastName
                         });

            return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(query.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Returns:

[{"id":3,"eventType_FK":4,"eventType":"Calendar","rowCreatedDT":"/Date(1544997181613)/","message":"Description Test 3.","userFullName":"System Admin"},{"id":2,"eventType_FK":1,"eventType":"Information","rowCreatedDT":"/Date(1544994918530)/","message":"Description Test 2.","userFullName":"System Admin"},{"id":1,"eventType_FK":1,"eventType":"Information","rowCreatedDT":"/Date(1544994006240)/","message":"Description Test 1.","userFullName":"System Admin"}]

Comment: have you checked its event source - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feedoption ?

Comment: You can get your calendar data from an api with `events` option

Comment: And check here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object to see what field names your events must have in order to be recognised by fullCalendar, and in what format the dates must be. Hint: you need at least `title` and `start`, and also possibly `end` as well. Currently you are not generating any of those fields. Read the documentation and examples more carefully!